# Accessing a EnumerableRowCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I cannot access the items from this query:

```
var elem = from e in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
           where e.Field<string>("price") == "-1" && 
                 e.Field<string>("val") == "-1"
           select e;
```

It returns EnumerableRowCollection, and how can i access the values? or copy to another dataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop, or call `CopyToDataTable()`.

If you only want to first item in the sequence, you can also call `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: it returns only one row, no necessary a foreach i think

Comment: If you only want the first item in the sequence, you can call `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @user2483797 The code you showed will create a sequence, not a single row.  It may be that that sequence contains only one item, based on your data, abut it's still a sequence.  As Slacks said, if you *want* just one item, you can grab the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.ToList()` to the end to get execute the LINQ statement and get your results (a list of DataRows):

```
var elem = (from e in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            where e.Field<string>("price") == "-1"
                  && e.Field<string>("val") == "-1"
            select e).ToList();
```

Then you could iterate through the results using a loop.

Comment: There is no need to create an extra `List<T>`.